# How to stop excessive memory usage of unity-window-decorator?

Tags: unity, memory-usage, window-decoration

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on an AMD64 computer. When I boot the computer the memory usage of unity-window-decorator is few tens of MB (checked with System Monitor)c After many hours using Google Chrome, LibreOffice, Kile, Skype etc. the memory usage for unity-window-decorator increases to almost 1 GB. Today I made sure that not many programs run simultaneously and quit them after each use.

Again as time passed the memory usage of the unity-window-decorator increased to almost 1 GB. Using `/usr/bin/unity-window-decorator --replace` the memory usage is reduced drastically but this time there are no window decorations. `/usr/bin/unity-window-decorator&` restarts the software thus bringing the window decorations but also starts the cycle of increased memory use again. What should I do to stop this excessive memory use?

Answer (score 3):

What you should do, is report a bug on http://www.Launchpad.net and provide as much information you can. There is no configuration option to deactivate memory leaks.

Comment: Here's a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/740258