# What is the difference between gtk-window-decorator and compiz-decorator?

Tags: unity, compiz, gtk

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and have installed CCSM.

I found that the default decorator was `/usr/bin/gtk-window-decorator`. Is it correct? I am using the user configurations (the home directory of my user and its contents) left by the previous operating system which is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on which I have used GNOME for my VNC server.

There are articles on the web who believe that the correct one should be `/usr/bin/compiz-decorator`, so what is the difference between them? Which one should be correct at all? And if compiz-decorator is correct, why it was replaced? I have never used CCSM before.

Comment: I think I also saw some reference somewhere to "unity-window-decorator" or "unity-decorator". Is that another one of these? Here's an [AskUbuntu reference](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63139/how-to-stop-excessive-memory-usage-of-unity-window-decorator).

Answer (score 0):

> using compiz-decorator just puts compiz in charge of picking the
>   decorator - which, subsequently, can enable emerald or others through
>   the compiz interface.

[reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1246543)

Comment: Do they have any relationship with the wake-up black border issues? http://askubuntu.com/questions/360598/13-10-black-borders-black-terminal

Comment: When I was using `gtk-window-decorator`, some times I wake up with black borders described in that post. Now I decided to change to `compiz-decorator`, will it possibly fix that?